# Manjaro/hashcat error : clGetPlatformIDs(): CL_PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR

Tags: drivers, manjaro

I'm currently on Manjaro.

When I run `hashcat`, I get the following error:

```
clGetPlatformIDs(): CL_PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR
```

Running `hashcat` with `sudo` gives the same error.

Having googled the error, I found that it's usually a driver problem with NVIDIA graphics cards so I tried some things with the drivers.

This is my NVIDIA info:

```
$ lspci -v | grep -i nvidia 
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1) 
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia 
        Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Upon trying to install the driver with `mhwd`, I get the following error:

```
$ sudo mhwd -a pci nonfree 0300
> Skipping already installed config 'video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-440xx-prime' for device: 0000:00:02.0 (0300:8086:591b) Display controller Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630
```

I checked my installed drivers and confirmed that it's installed:

```
$ pacman -Qs nvidia 
local/lib32-nvidia-440xx-utils 440.64-1 
    NVIDIA drivers utilities (32-bit) 
local/libvdpau 1.3-1 
    Nvidia VDPAU library 
local/linux54-nvidia-440xx 440.64-2 (linux54-extramodules) 
    NVIDIA drivers for linux. 
local/mhwd-nvidia-340xx 340.108-1 
    MHWD module-ids for nvidia 340.108 
local/mhwd-nvidia-390xx 390.132-1 
    MHWD module-ids for nvidia 390.132 
local/mhwd-nvidia-418xx 418.113-1 
    MHWD module-ids for nvidia-418xx 418.113 
local/mhwd-nvidia-430xx 430.64-1.0 
    MHWD module-ids for nvidia-430xx 430.64 
local/mhwd-nvidia-435xx 435.21-1.0 
    MHWD module-ids for nvidia 435.21 
local/mhwd-nvidia-440xx 440.64-1 
    MHWD module-ids for nvidia 440.64 
local/nvidia-440xx-utils 440.64-1 
    NVIDIA drivers utilities 
local/nvidia-prime 1.0-1 
    NVIDIA Prime Render Offload configuration and utilities
```

When I tried uninstalling the seemingly unnecessary drivers, I got dependency errors:

```
$ sudo pacman -Rns local/mhwd-nvidia-340xx local/mhwd-nvidia-390xx local/mhwd-nvidia-418xx local/mhwd-nvidia-430xx local/mhwd-nvidia-435xx 
checking dependencies... 
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies) 
:: removing mhwd-nvidia-340xx breaks dependency 'mhwd-nvidia-340xx' required by mhwd-db 
:: removing mhwd-nvidia-390xx breaks dependency 'mhwd-nvidia-390xx' required by mhwd-db 
:: removing mhwd-nvidia-418xx breaks dependency 'mhwd-nvidia-418xx' required by mhwd-db 
:: removing mhwd-nvidia-430xx breaks dependency 'mhwd-nvidia-430xx' required by mhwd-db 
:: removing mhwd-nvidia-435xx breaks dependency 'mhwd-nvidia-435xx' required by mhwd-db
```

Of course, `mhwd-db` can't be uninstalled because of `mhwd`.

I checked `nvidia-settings` but don't know what exactly I should do here.

[image: nvidia-settings]

I've also seen mentions of `bumblebee` but I'm not sure if I should use it.

How can I fix the error `clGetPlatformIDs(): CL_PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR`?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very late answer, but I had the same issue and i was just able to fix it.

To run hascat you need OpenCL and CUDA (if your GPU supports it). I have a RTX 2070 and when installing cuda with:

```
sudo pacman -S cuda
```

I was able to choose the opencl package, disigned for my installed driver. I have the driver version 455.x installed and so I chose the option for opencl_nvidia-455xx.

After the installation of opencl and cuda everything worked fine.